# counter on link_to ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 3 link with images. When I click on link I want add my count +1.

```
<a href="/home" id="push"><img src="/images/image1.gif" /></a>
<a href="/faq"> <img src="/images/image2.gif" /></a>
<a href="/news"><img src="/images/image3.gif" /></a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#push").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "room/room_count", type: "POST"});
  });
</script>
```

**in my controller**

```
 def room_count
   count_method = Room.find 1
   count_method.update_attribute(:count, count_method.count.to_i + 1)
 end
```

If I click on link count don't update, but if I replase href="/home" on href="#" all works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is kind of risky, here you could click tons of times on the link and vote a lot. There is no comparison with the "voter IP", maybe you should introduce a IP-saving system in your Database: if you want to do so, you can use `request.ip` in your controller to get the requester's ip ;)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the onclick within the href would offend those who believe strongly in separation of content from behavior/action. The argument is that your html content should remain focused solely on content, not on presentation or behavior.

The typical path these days is to use a javascript library (eg. jquery) and create an event handler using that library. It would look something like:

```
$("#push").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "room/room_count", type: "POST"});
      return false;
  });
```